# Postmodel refinement to ServiceDetail page (deduplicating code query)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Query: In the MVC we have some Postmodels, with modification to the ServiceDetails.cs can they be removed?

Notes: I'm fairly new to MVC but feel this could be improved, one way or another. (i.e. there's duplication here)
For example:
In ServiceDetails.cs we have:

```
  #region ClassName
        [Display(Name = "Text user sees")]
        [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Blah textbox many only contain up to {1} characters")]
        public string MyString { get; set; }
     #endregion
```

and in the postmodel I have:

```
public class ClassName
    {      
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error message goes here")]
        [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Repeating how many only contain up to {1} characters")]
        public string DamageInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I've edited the question. We have code in a postmodel, but it's almost duplicated in the ServiceDetail, bar forcing it to be 'required', which appears not to work if you put it in the ServiceDetail.cs I was wondering if I can remove the postmodel, and put the requirement in the ServiceDetail page

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly you are asking if you can remove the post model and use the entity itself. **The answer is you can, but it's better not to.**

You are referring to only one property and it may look unnecessary to have a post model but in long term is the best thing to have. 
**You should always separate the business logic.**